# How to call the Android keyboards ok button function in HTML5

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I'm using the code below to create a form. Using this in a android device shows a ok button when the keyboard shows up. I've seen alot of questions on how to show different keyboards. Yet i cant seem to find/figure out how to use my own function once this ok button has been clicked using javascript/jquery.

```
    <form id="AndroidForm">
        <input id="myforminput" type="url" maxlength="20">
    </form>
```

If anyone has any input about how it can be done, i'd appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Using `event.keycode === 13`

Comment: This seems like an X/Y question. is there some specific functionality you're trying to invoke on this button, or do you just want to submit the form? The  latter would be just `$('#AndroidForm').submit()`

Comment: @Rayon Keycode === 13 did it, thanks

Comment: @mattias, I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_